# CSS Colocar dados no centro

Tags: css

Estou a utilizar css para construir tabelas e quero colocar os dados no centro e não estou a conseguir.

CSS:

```
.tabla7 .columna7 {
 padding: 5px;
 height: 45px;
 float:left;width:89px;
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes usar o `vertical-align:middle;`

Comment: Utilizei isso e não alterou nada.

Comment: Você quer centralizar o conteúdo da tabela ou a tabela em relação à página?

Comment: Tens de retirar o `float:left;`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b32Sn/13/)